# How to use Ext.list.Tree component in an application?

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, tree

[Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) add a component with [Ext.list.Tree](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.list.Tree).  I want to use this component in my application. But I do everything and I'm not successful.

**How can I use this component**? **Can you present any sample code**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This control can be found in the examples of ExtJs. You can find it in the online examples here:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard

It can also be found in the KitchenSink examples (with source):
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-list

You can also find it in the source code as downloaded from Sencha. It should be in the examples folder and it is called SenchaDash.

Comment: yes I did it. but I can't run it. It use a another class

Comment: I added the KitchenSink example. It does have source available. Hope this helps you out. Otherwise you should provide more code of what you are attempting..